# Is it possible to determine which combination of three degenerate states an atom is in, not destroying the state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements

Suppose we have somehow determined that an atom's outer shell electron is in a $p$ state (i.e. with $l=1$). For example, waited enough for a cold boron atom to almost certainly come into electronic ground state.

Since the $p$ shell has threefold degeneracy, the atom now is in some state like

$$\newcommand\ket[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}
\alpha\ket{m=-1}+\beta\ket{m=0}+\gamma\ket{m=1}.$$

Having chosen some $z$ axis, can we find differences of phases and magnitudes between $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ without destroying or only slightly changing the atom's state? If yes, then how? If no, why?

**EDIT** OK, it seems that by no-cloning theorem this can't be done perfectly. But what about approximate measurement of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$?

Comment: I am not sure about one thin: which axis in the space is the $z$ axis? The Boron atom in the $p$ state has some preferred axis in the space?

Comment: @Sofia I've said that we've _chosen_ some $z$ axis, thus fixed our spherical harmonic basis. Otherwise it wouldn't make any sense to measure the $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: if so, no hope. You see, if along a certain axis in space we have well-determined $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, then there should exist another axis on which we have $\alpha = \gamma = 0$ and $\beta = 1$. It's matter of transformation of the eigenfunctions of $\ell = 1$. If we knew that there exists some preferred direction in space, we could manage to determine $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ by knowing the angle of the $z$ axis that we picked.

Comment: @Sofia no, that's wrong. If you choose e.g. $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=1$ and try to plot such a combination of spherical functions, you'll see it doesn't look like a rotated $m=0$ spherical function - it's much distorted.

Comment: there is a law of transformation between the eigenstates of $L_z$ and the eigenstates of $L$ along other axes. Unfortunately I don't find the unitary matrix that transforms between these states. But your state with given $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ has to be an eigenstate of the projection of $\vec L$ on some axis.

Comment: @Sofia no, that'd only be true if the $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ were proportional to corresponding matrix elements of [Wigner matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix). In general, this is false.

Comment: please follow me. It's not a matrix, it's a vector. Let's say that we want to find a direction, $\theta, \phi$ s.t. your vector be the eigenvector for $m = 0$ of the projection of $\vec L$ on that direction. O.K.? Then we only have to find $\theta$ and $\phi$. Right? (I continue)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20234/discussion-between-ruslan-and-sofia).

Comment: Now, with God's help, I found the transformation. And the vector looks as follows : $(\frac {1 + cos \theta}{2}e^{i \phi}, -\frac {sin \theta}{\sqrt {2}}, \frac {1 - cos \theta}{2}e^{-i \phi})$. Now, set the three elements equal respectively to $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and find $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Comment: we can continue in chat, but meanwhile look at what I said in the last comment. You just made a confusion because of that complicated Wigner matrix.

Comment: As we cannot clone the state, a non-demolition measurement in this case can be done if we know the state, and we only test it. For testing the state, we can simply rotate it, laying it for instance on the state $m_{\theta, \phi} = 0$ of the projection of $\vec L$ on the direction $\theta, \phi$, see my before last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is an instance of *state estimation* for a qutrit in some state 
$$|\psi⟩=\alpha|-1⟩+\beta|0⟩+\gamma|1⟩$$
using a single copy of the state. This is essentially impossible, due mostly to the no-cloning theorem. The most you can do is choose some orthogonal basis $\{|a⟩,|b⟩,|c⟩\}$, and measure along it, which will get you a hit on only one of the states, say $|a⟩$. **The only information you will get from that is that** 
$$⟨a|\psi⟩\neq0.$$
That is, you can conclude that the component of $|\psi⟩$ along some chosen vector is nonzero. However, this does not (and cannot) give you any information about the magnitude of this component, or about the existence or not of components along vectors orthogonal to $|a⟩$.

It's important to note that this procedure will completely destroy the state, and this is pretty much a necessary condition for gaining any information about it.

The case of a qubit is slightly easier to understand geometrically. There, if you measure on a basis $\{|a⟩,|b⟩\}$ and get $|a⟩$, then you know that the state is *not* on the state $|b⟩$; that is, you know a single point on the Bloch sphere that the state vector doesn't point along. However, this does not rule out points very close to that forbidden point (for which $⟨a|\psi⟩$ is small but nonzero).

Quantum states really are very dark black boxes. If you have axes to the box factory - that is, if you have access to multiple copies of states produced by the same preparation - then you can perform tomography on the boxes and get a fairly good idea of what the state is (including whether it's pure or mixed). The theory of [quantum state tomography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tomography) tells you how many different measurements you need to perform to estimate the state, depending on its dimensionality. However, it's important to note that each 'measurement' is itself performed on an ensemble of boxes and aims to estimate a given probability. If you only have access to a finite number of boxes, this will bound the accuracy of your tomography, in well-studied ways.

If you only have a single box, though, there's very little indeed that you can say.